# Javascript library for flowcharting

Tags: open-source, javascript, java, html, css

I have a requirement for modelling flowchart like (workflows) diagrams in the Web application.

Request suggestions for an open-source javascript library for the same.

Features I am looking include drag-drop, connectors, 1-1 and 1-to-many relationships, auto arrange. Requesting recommendations to make the UI responsive, and gel with existing CSS frameworks.

I am quite new to front end development, any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does [Alternatives to GoJS for flowchart](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/41703/alternatives-to-gojs-for-flowchart) help any?

Comment: Oh, I see, you have not logged in since two days after posting this, 3.5 years ago. I guess that you are unlikely to accept an answer, then :-/

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul Please undelete my answer because the other answer is also not open source.

Comment: Sorry, Davis. I missed the [tag:open-source] tag. Nine times out of ten the OP actually means [tag:gratis] ans either isn't aware of its existence or doesn't understand the difference. Still, it's not for me to second guess, so I thought about deleting the answer. It is highly unlikely that the OP will ever come back, so (s)he won't care, but I will leave the answer - with a **BOLD** explanation that it is not open-source in case it can help anyone in future, who has similar requirements, but does not require open source.

Comment: @Mawg I don't see where GoJS is gratis? Looks like it requires a paid license. Essential Diagram JS is open source as the source is available on Github and it is free for users with less than a million USD in revenue so my answer should be undeleted if Go JS answer remains. Thanks.

Comment: Wah!! You are correct! Free for academic porpoises, else pretty darned expensive. I apologize. What do you think, should I delete the answer (I don't mind doing that), or just update to mention the price?

Comment: nPingali: By "open source", did you mean you want a solution where you can modify and redistribute the source code (as written in the tag description)? Or did you just mean gratis? Or did you just mean a solution whose source code can be viewed, even if it can not be redistributed freely?

Comment: @Mawg I leave it your discretion. I am fine with your answer remaining as someone could benefit from it and believe the same applies to my answer also.

Comment: OK, I will leave it - with a ***BIG*** warning :-)  I hope that your answer is undeleted. Thanks

Comment: He he . Now mine is deleted too. That's fine. I editted it mention the price (even though it is deleted), in case anyone who can see delete answers checks it out. I hope this gets an answers, as I would like one :-) The OP is never coming back to accept any answer, though

Comment: Whoever is deleting is applying the interpretation for open-source in an unnecessarily strict manner that combines open-source with gratis.

Answer (score 1):

I take the requirement "open-source" as defined in the [tag wiki](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tags/open-source/info), i.e. that you want to be able to modify and redistribute the source code.

Your best choice currently is [JointJS](https://github.com/clientIO/joint), which is licensed under the MPL-2. There is a [demo](http://resources.jointjs.com/demos), which seems to do most of what you want, but JointJS, the free part, is actually embedded in Rappid, a commercial wrapper around JointJS. Not sure, what part of the demo is Rappid and what is JointJS.

An alternative might be [jsPlumb Community Edition](https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb). In the [demo](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demos.html) the sophistication of the elements seems to be a bit less than for JointJS. Also there, only the [Community Edition](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/features) is actually open source (MIT and GPL-2).

Finally, [jsUML2](http://www.jrromero.net/tools/jsUML2) might be useful, distributed under GPL-3 and last updated in 2017. The [demo](http://www.jrromero.net/tools/jsUML2) shows mostly class diagrams, but one could probably use it for displaying flow charts.