# Alternatives to GoJS for flowchart

Tags: javascript, workflow, diagram

After a round of research, **GoJS** seems to be the specialist in javascript components for charts related to flowcharts, workflows, org-charts, etc. Here is an example **[flowchart](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html)**. Their api and examples are both extensive, yet I am primarily interested in their flowcharts.

Under certain circumstances, some javascript ui vendors offer potentially less expensive licenses for libraries that offer similar flowchart diagram capabilities, though not as robust as GoJS. Two examples I have come across are from Kendo UI and from Syncfusion.

1. **[Kendo UI - diagram component](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/diagram/index)**
2. **[Syncfusion - diagram component](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejdiagram)**

What would be helpful to know:

1. What vendors - excluding GoJS, yet like Kendo UI and Syncfusion - offer commercial javascript components for flowcharts? I'm *not* interested freeware, as what open-source alternatives I found were insufficient, unless one is prepared to do a lot of work on one's own.
2. If you are someone has experience with both the Kendo UI and Syncfusion diagram components, have you found advantages in one library vs the other in terms of diagrams - in particular, flowcharts? At first glance, the Kendo UI diagram component does not seem as feature-rich as the Syncfusion component (yet some of the other items in Kendo UI's pro package seem better than Syncfusion's - oh, well.)

Comment: Please note that your "part 2" (product comparison) is explicitly off-topic here, see [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/69/185). Part 1 (vendors) is questionable at best: SR is about recommending *software,* not companies/vendors. You surely don't want to ask for vendors, but for "libraries" (aka "Javascript components") to use? May I recommend you [edit] your question and rephrase it accordingly – including your requirements (what features you need, your price limit, etc)?

Comment: Thank you for considering Syncfusion. Syncfusion Diagram can do flow charts as well. Please contact Syncfusion [support](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/) or post here if you have any specific requirements.

Comment: You didn't find mxGraph or it wasn't good enough?

Comment: @David - re: mxGraph - yes, I did come across it. Looks powerful, but the learning curve looks steeper, the api more complex, examples did not seem to do so look so good in mobile view in Chrome; the other vendors (not that I'll use them) already have running examples with angularjs, export for printing, etc.